# I'm having gaming problems

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I have a game on my phone that I want to restart and play from the beginning. How can I Erase the data to start over?

Comment: really, you have a game! good for you :)

Comment: It depends on the game and what the developers have provided you will have to ask them

Answer (score 2):

If it's a game that doesn't save your stats in the cloud the simplest way would be to delete and redownload the app.